# Reference request-One-shot deviation principle

Tags: reference-request, game-theory

I'm writing the presentation for a seminar on the theory of coalition formation, following the approach of a 1999 article by Ray Debraj and Rajiv Vohra. I noticed that the authors implicitly use several times in proofs (without stating it outright) a special form of something that (after a bit of searching on google) I found is called the "one-shot deviation principle". I'd like a reference for the general idea of this principle to include it in the presentation. Any standard text would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original article:

- Blackwell, D. (1965). *Discounting Dynamic Programming*. Annals of
  Mathematical Statistics: 36(1) 226–235.

Standard textbook reference:

- Mailath, G., and Samuelson, L. (2006) *Repeated Games and Reputations: Long-Run Relationships*. Oxford University Press.